# Armazenar usuário logado em variável .bat

Tags: windows, bash, batch

Tenho que criar um bat para automatizar a instalação dos programas padrão da empresa, mas um em específico está me dando dor de cabeça.

O instalador de um dos programas, por padrão, cria o caminho 
**C:\app\client\\product\12.1.0\client_1** 
para instalação. Porém eu preciso substituir um arquivo dentro da pasta de instalação após ele ser instalado.

A substituição do arquivo estaria OK se não fosse o nome do usuário no caminho gerado pelo instalador do programa. Eu até poderia trocar o caminho, mas a ideia é automatizar tudo, de forma que o usuário clique em *next* > *next* > *next* sem precisar olhar o que está fazendo.

Minha dúvida é: Como eu pego o nome de usuário da sessão atual do windows (10 PRO, se a versão fizer diferença), e armazená-lo em uma variável.

Tentei usar o `WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME` mas não consigo armazenar em variável.

Para ser sincero não conheço muito de programação bash, mas é só essa parte do código que está faltando e não consigo resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variável global **`%username%`**.

Comment: Muito obrigado, era basicamente isso. Estava dando uma volta absurda pra resolver o problema!!!